# guess.php error log

Tags: log-files

last night i got a weird php error log. i have never seen this before on my server and i dont know what it means.

I really appreciate if you know about it.

```
[10-Nov-2010 01:48:08] PHP Warning:  popen() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/lib/php/OS/Guess.php on line 247
[10-Nov-2010 01:48:08] PHP Warning:  fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /usr/lib/php/OS/Guess.php on line 248
[10-Nov-2010 01:48:08] PHP Warning:  pclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /usr/lib/php/OS/Guess.php on line 256
[10-Nov-2010 01:48:43] PHP Warning:  popen() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/lib/php/OS/Guess.php on line 242
[10-Nov-2010 01:48:43] PHP Warning:  fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /usr/lib/php/OS/Guess.php on line 243
[10-Nov-2010 01:48:43] PHP Warning:  pclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /usr/lib/php/OS/Guess.php on line 252
```

what is that guess.php ? and why i am getting error ?

thank you

Comment: If you don't know what code is configured on the server, and when policy changes are implemented, then I can only assume that either its not your server - its a hosted one (in which case why are you paying a hosting company for support and asking these questions here) or it really is your server and your system has been seriously compromised (in which case this is the least of your worries)

Answer (score 0):

The file `Guess.php` belongs to the PHP PEAR Module OS_Guess, used to retrieve information about the current operating system

The messages you are receiving tell you that:

```
popen() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/lib/php/OS/Guess.php on line 247
```

popen() is used to open communication to another process and is disabled in many setups for security considerations. The other errors you receive are follow-up errors because popen() did fail.

See the [php.net/popen](http://php.net/popen) for more details on this function.

Comment: yeah. but the thing is i have been using my server almost 1 year and i got this error for the first time, what havent i got it before ?

Comment: and what should i do now ? should i remove popen from disabled_functions ?

Comment: popen MIGHT be a potential security risk. I cannot help you in choosing or not whether it is safe for you or not. Since this just a library from PEAR it doesn't give information from which application it get's called.